# PHP parse syntax error

Tags: php

I am new to PHP and I am facing a syntax error.

**Code:**

```
<?php

    // configuration
    require("../includes/config.php");

    // if form was submitted
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
        if(empty($_POST['username'])) || empty($_POST['password'] || $_POST['password'] != $_POST['confirmation']){
            apologize('You did something wrong!');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // else render form
        render("register_form.php", ["title" => "Register"]);
    }

?>
```

**Error:**

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '||' (T_BOOLEAN_OR), expecting ')' in /home/jharvard/vhosts/localhost/html/register.php on line 9

I am very new to PHP and it is possible this code has multiple bugs.
For reference, apologize simply renders a sorry message along with additional inputs, and render is just a function to simplify the rendering process with templates.

Comment: `if(empty($_POST['username']))` you have an extra parenthesis that closes the if statements

Comment: PHP errors almost always give you enough information to find problem. If you learn to read erros you'll never have problem with syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Too many brackets. instead of

```
if(empty($_POST['username'])) || empty($_POST['password'] || $_POST['password'] != $_POST['confirmation']){
                            ^                            ^
                            too much here                too less here
```

you should have

```
if( empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password']) || $_POST['password'] != $_POST['confirmation']) {
```

Comment: you are missing a bracket

Comment: Thanks, you and prankrates pointed out both the errors :D

Answer (score 5):

Change:

```
if(empty($_POST['username'])) || empty($_POST['password'] || $_POST['password'] != $_POST['confirmation']){
```

to:

```
if(empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password']) || $_POST['password'] != $_POST['confirmation']){
                           ^                            ^
```

Comment: don't just post two lines of code that differ by single chars. use a second line with `^^^` to indicate WHERE you made the change.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of too many paranethesis. Try this,

```
 if(empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password']) || ($_POST['password'] != $_POST['confirmation'])){
        apologize('You did something wrong!');
    }
```